# Deploying Angular app with express displaying blank page

Tags: angular, express, heroku

I'm attempting a minimal setup up heroku, when i try to serve my angular 17 app via express, I get a blank page but the console contains these errors. Note, this is running locally on my machine before deplying to heroku
[image]

server.js

```
//Install express server
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Serve only the static files form the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/nwp-rd-dashboard'));
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/nwp-rd-dashboard/browser/index.html'));
});

// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

below is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nwp-rd-dashboard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --configurations=production"
    },
  "engines": {
    "node": "20.9.0",
    "npm": "10.1.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.5",
    "typescript": "~5.2.2"
  }
}
```

and my file structure after a production build:

[image]

and my index.html after build -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-critters-container>
<head><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NwpRdDashboard</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <style type="text/css">@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu72xKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu5mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0301, U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0370-03FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+0300-0301, U+0303-0304, U+0308-0309, U+0323, U+0329, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7GxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-02AF, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+1E00-1E9F, U+1EF2-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxKKTU1Kg.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfABc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0301, U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfCBc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfBxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0370-03FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfCxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+0300-0301, U+0303-0304, U+0308-0309, U+0323, U+0329, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfChc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-02AF, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+1E00-1E9F, U+1EF2-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v30/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfBBc4AMP6lQ.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}</style>

<style>*,:before,:after{box-sizing:border-box;border-width:0;border-style:solid;border-color:#e5e7eb}:before,:after{--tw-content: ""}html{line-height:1.5;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-moz-tab-size:4;tab-size:4;font-family:ui-sans-serif,system-ui,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica Neue,Arial,Noto Sans,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji",Segoe UI Symbol,"Noto Color Emoji";font-feature-settings:normal;font-variation-settings:normal}body{margin:0;line-height:inherit}*,:before,:after{--tw-border-spacing-x: 0;--tw-border-spacing-y: 0;--tw-translate-x: 0;--tw-translate-y: 0;--tw-rotate: 0;--tw-skew-x: 0;--tw-skew-y: 0;--tw-scale-x: 1;--tw-scale-y: 1;--tw-pan-x: ;--tw-pan-y: ;--tw-pinch-zoom: ;--tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;--tw-gradient-from-position: ;--tw-gradient-via-position: ;--tw-gradient-to-position: ;--tw-ordinal: ;--tw-slashed-zero: ;--tw-numeric-figure: ;--tw-numeric-spacing: ;--tw-numeric-fraction: ;--tw-ring-inset: ;--tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;--tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;--tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / .5);--tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;--tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;--tw-blur: ;--tw-brightness: ;--tw-contrast: ;--tw-grayscale: ;--tw-hue-rotate: ;--tw-invert: ;--tw-saturate: ;--tw-sepia: ;--tw-drop-shadow: ;--tw-backdrop-blur: ;--tw-backdrop-brightness: ;--tw-backdrop-contrast: ;--tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;--tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;--tw-backdrop-invert: ;--tw-backdrop-opacity: ;--tw-backdrop-saturate: ;--tw-backdrop-sepia: }body{font-family:Roboto,sans-serif}
</style><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-JAGPJCWC.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-JAGPJCWC.css"></noscript></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="polyfills-LZBJRJJE.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-M7FI6AH7.js" type="module"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can try to use angular's Server Sider Rendering package, which uses express and configure's it to work properly. All you have to do is to run `ng add @angular/ssr`